# access_token not required for Implicit Grant Flow?

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal, adal.js

We are trying to integrate adal.js to access EWS API, and our app is implemented using Angular 1.5.8. After successfully login, it redirects back to the app home page with id_token. According to the following link from MS:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-implicit
we suppose to use access_token instead of id_token to talk to EWS API.

> Now that you've signed the user into your single page app, you can get access tokens for calling web APIs secured by Azure AD, such as the Microsoft Graph.

So we are trying to use `adalAuthenticationService.acquireToken` with valid clientId. But the token we got is the same as `id_token`. Is there anything we did wrong?

```js
 // configure our routes
 testApp.config(function($httpProvider, $locationProvider, $routeProvider, adalAuthenticationServiceProvider) {

  $locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
  }).hashPrefix('!');

  $routeProvider

   // route for the home page
   .when('/', {
    templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
    controller  : 'mainController',
    requireADLogin: true
   })

        adalAuthenticationServiceProvider.init({
            // clientId is the identifier assigned to your app by Azure Active Directory.
            clientId: "TEST_CLIENT_ID",
            cacheLocation: 'localStorage', // optional cache location default is sessionStorage
        }, $httpProvider);
  
 });
```

```js
 // create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
 testApp.controller('mainController', function($scope, adalAuthenticationService) {
  // create a message to display in our view
  $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';
  $scope.getAccessToken = getAccessToken;

  function getAccessToken() {
   adalAuthenticationService.acquireToken('TEST_CLIENT_ID', (newToken) => {
    console.log('Access token aquired: ' + newToken);
   }, (error) => {
    console.log('ERROR with token: ' + angular.toJson(error, true));
   });
  };
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code doesn't seem to tell the `acquireToken` call which resource it wants a token for. Do you set that somewhere else?

Otherwise you should add the resource URL "https://outlook.office365.com" as the resource parameter to the `acquireToken` call.

Comment: Thanks @RasmusW for the answer. I am indeed very confused about this resource URL parameter. Seems to me that we have to specify loginResource from the configuration object. Otherwise, it will simply default to clientId during AuthenticationContext initialization process.
Is it a good assumption that we should always hard-code that resource URL to https://outlook.office.com? Thanks

Comment: The resource URL is what you want the access token to grant you access to. If you wanted access to the Azure AD graph API, it would be graph.windows.net, etc. For EWS it is outlook.office.com.

Comment: Thanks. That's pretty useful info. One last question, I do see for office 365 we should be using url: https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx to access EWS managed API. In that case, should our resource url be:  https://outlook.office365.com? Thanks